# Artificial Neural Network - Compiling error

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, spyder

I am learning Deep Learning myself and am facing issues while performing ANN. Here's what I am doing:

Initializing the ANN (I've split the dataset beforehand):

```
classifier = Sequential()
```

Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer:

```
classifier.add(Dense(input_dim = 11, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', units = 6))
```

Adding the second hidden layer:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
```

Adding the output layer:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Compiling the ANN by employing Stochastic gradient descent:

```
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

After this, when I select and run the last command, I get an error that reads:

```
TypeError: sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

I noticed when I use `loss = mean_squared_error`, it compiles fine. Can you tell me what's going on?

`Sypder` and `Python` latest as on the day I am posting this. 
`Windows 10`.
Thanos, TensorFlow and Keras latest

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your tensorflow version with a nightly build:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation

see this issue:https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/issues/84

Comment: Updated - but still the same. How can I tell what version of TF am I running, GPU or CPU? Any possibility I've got both?

Comment: Not nightly build, but I simply updated TF. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow changed keyword names for this function, and you are probably using outdated version of either tf or keras, update both and you should be good to go.

Comment: I just got them installed today, so must be updated, right? Could it be that the tutorial I am going through is using an older version?

Comment: Very likely, skim through the documentation of everything you write from a tutorial to make sure that it is still valid.

Comment: But in https://keras.io/losses/, binary_crossentropy shows up under **Available loss functions**. So I still don't understand! Does it have to do anything with the sigmoid function I am using in the output layer?

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting, I changed the Sigmoid Function in the output layer to `tanh` and then to `relu`, still the same error. So it isn't related to that. Can someone help me out please?!

Comment: This is only loss related, as I said - TF changed naming convention, thus you might get out-of-sync versions, that's all. This has nothing to do with activation functions.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install -U tensorflow` fixed the issue for me